# How to stringfy a swig matrix object in python

Tags: python, swig

I am using swig wrapper of [openbabel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Developer:Python_Tutorial) (written in C++, and supply a python wrapper through swig)

Below i just use it to read a molecule structure file and get the unitcell property of it.

```
import pybel
for molecule in pybel.readfile('pdb','./test.pdb'):
    unitcell = molecule.unitcell
    print unitcell
   |..>     
   |..>     
<openbabel.OBUnitCell; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OpenBabel::OBUnitCell *' at 0x17b390c0> >
```

The unitcell has function CellMatrix(),

```
unitcell.GetCellMatrix()
   <22> <openbabel.matrix3x3; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OpenBabel::matrix3x3 *' at 0x17b3ecf0> >
```

the OpenBabel::matrix3x3 is something like :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

i am wondering how to print out the contents of the matrix3*3 . I have tried `__str__` and `__repr__` with it.

Any general way to stringfy the contents of a matrix wrapped by swing in python ?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Based on this openbabel documentation, it looks like there is a good reason the Python bindings don't come with a nice way to print a `matrix3x3 object`. The `matrix3x3` C++ class overloads the `<<` operator, which SWIG will simply ignore:

http://openbabel.org/api/2.2.0/classOpenBabel_1_1matrix3x3.shtml

This means that you'll need to modify your SWIG interface file (look at http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_class_extension) to add a `__str__` method to `openbabel::matrix3x3` in C++ which wraps the `<<` operator. Your method might look a lot like

```
std::string __str__() {
  //make sure you include sstream in the SWIG interface file
  std::ostringstream oss(std::ostringstream::out);
  oss << (*this);
  return oss.str();
}
```

I believe that SWIG will properly handle C++ a return type of `std::string` in this case, but if not you might have to play around with returning a character array.

At this point, you should be able to recompile the bindings, and rerun your Python code. Calling `str()` on a `matrix3x3` object should now display what would be displayed with the `<<` operator in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the answer from @jhoon, it seems that SWIG doesn't recognise the *std::string* return type so change the function to return *const char**. Also, since it is a function outside the class, you can't use self but you must use SWIG's *$self* variable.

So, in the SWIG *.i* file, if you put the following:

```
%extend OpenBabel::matrix3x3 {
  const char* __str__() {
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << *$self;
    return out.str().c_str();
  }
};
```

you should get the desired result when calling Python's print on a *matrix3x3*.

If you find yourself adding this to many classes, consider wrapping it in a macro like:

```
%define __STR__()
const char* __str__() {
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << *$self;
  return out.str().c_str();
}
%enddef
```

and then adding it to the class with:

```
%extend OpenBabel::matrix3x3 {
  __STR__()
};
```

Comment: Two problems with this answer: 1. the memory pointed to is released before you return from your function and 2. SWIG does support `std::string`, but you need to do `%include <std_string.i>` first.

Comment: @flexo Thanks a million for pointing the 2nd point out!