# __str__() not called when printing C++ class wrapped for Python with SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm trying to print C++ classes that I wrapped for Python using SWIG. I have followed the documentation and this question: [How to stringfy a swig matrix object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548779/how-to-stringfy-a-swig-matrix-object-in-python)

The extended `__str__` function is there, but it isn't called when I print the object from Python. Let me give a minimal example:

TestClass.h

```
#include <iostream> 

class TestClass{
private:
    int my_int;
public:
    TestClass():
        my_int(0)
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, TestClass const& t){
        o<< "TestClass: " << t.my_int;
        return o;
    }
};
```

TestClass.cpp

```
#include "TestClass.h"

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    TestClass t;
    cout << t << endl;
}
```

TestClass.i

```
%define __STR__() \
const char* __str__() { 
  std::cout << *$self << std::endl;
  std::ostringstream out; 
  out << *$self; \
  return out.str().c_str(); 
}

const char* __unicode__() { 
  std::cout << "unicode: " << *$self << std::endl;
  std::ostringstream out; 
  out << *$self; \
  return out.str().c_str(); 
}
%enddef

%extend TestClass{
    __STR__()
};
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (battery_lib_cpp)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE 1)

FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "-Wall")

#look for Pythonlibs
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(TestClass.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
SET_PROPERTY(SOURCE TestClass.i PROPERTY SWIG_FLAGS "-builtin")

SWIG_ADD_MODULE(TestClass python TestClass.i TestClass.cpp)
```

After building (cmake ., make), I then get the following:

```
matthias@rp3deb:~/dvl/swig_str_minimal$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 26 2014, 15:25:14) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import TestClass
>>> t = TestClass.TestClass()
>>> print t
<Swig Object of type 'TestClass *' at 0x7f1dffcb2b90>
>>> print t.__str__()
TestClass: 0
TestClass: 0
>>> print t.__str__
<built-in method __str__ of TestClass object at 0x7f1dffcb2b90>
```

Another test for `__unicode__()`

```
>>> import TestClass
>>> t = TestClass.TestClass()
>>> print str(t)
<Swig Object of type 'TestClass *' at 0x7f6584ae4b58>
>>> print t
<Swig Object of type 'TestClass *' at 0x7f6584ae4b58>
>>> print t.__unicode__()
unicode: TestClass: 0
TestClass: 0
>>> print t.__unicode__
<built-in method __unicode__ of TestClass object at 0x7f6584ae4b58>
```

Expected output would be to have `__str__()` called at "print t" implicitly. What am I missing?

Comment: What does `str(t)` return?

Comment: And: could it be that `__unicode__` is called here?

Comment: These are good ideas. Got kinda excited. Unfortunately didn't work; I added the return values above.

Comment: Why do you only have backslashes on a few of the lines? The placement seems strange.

Comment: I don't remember why I added the backslashes in the macro anymore; I removed them and it seems that this doesn't change the behavior. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `str(x)` to call your own C++ code for a SWIG wrapped object that was produced with `swig -python -builtin` you need to use the appropriate slot to register your function. That's done with `%feature("python:slot", ...)` in SWIG, e.g.:

```cpp
%module test

%include <std_string.i>

%feature("python:slot", "tp_str", functype="reprfunc") foo::as_string;

%inline %{
struct foo {
  std::string as_string() const { return "Hello world"; }
};
%}
```

With SWIG 2.0 and Python 2.7 lets me run:

```py
import test

print str(test.foo())
print repr(test.foo())
```

Which results in:

```
Hello world
<Swig Object of type 'foo *' at 0xb727ac40>
```

Slots allow standard object function calls to be dispatched quickly - it's a big chunk of what `-builtin` gains you.

You can see the complete [list of available slots](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html) and their types and the corresponding [SWIG 2.0 documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_builtin_overloads) of them.

Comment: This works, thank you!
I amended the __STR__() macro and posted it as separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon Flexo's answer, this got me the functionality I wanted (source files and cmake unchanged).

TestClass.i

```
%module TestClass

%{
#include <sstream>
#include "TestClass.h"
%}
%include "TestClass.h"

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548779/how-to-stringfy-a-swig-matrix-object-in-python
%define __STR__(class_name) 
%feature("python:slot", "tp_str", functype="reprfunc") class_name::py_to_string();

%extend class_name{
    const char* py_to_string() { 
      std::ostringstream out; 
      out << *$self; 
      return out.str().c_str(); 
    }
}
%enddef

__STR__(TestClass);
```

Testing:

```
matthias@rp3deb:~/dvl/swig_str_minimal$ python -c "import TestClass; print TestClass.TestClass()"
TestClass: 0
```

Comment: thinking about it, the macro should probably be called ADDSTRING(class_name) to avoid underscores...

Comment: reading Flexo's comment on the linked answer; it seems that going with char* here is not a good idea; #include <string> and use std::string instead.