# How do I wrap the operator<< to __str__ in Python using SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, swig

If I want to print information about an object in C++, I'll use the outstream operator `<<`:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Foo& foo);
private:
    double bar = 7;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Foo& foo)
{
    return out << foo.bar;
}
```

Then, I can do `Foo foo; std::cout << foo << std::endl;`. Something equivalent in Python would be implementing `__str__` and then saying `print(foo)`.  But since the operator is not really a member of `Foo`, I don't know how to do this in SWIG.

What would I have to write in my interface file to reuse my implementation of the outstream operator for use in `print()`?

Additionally, is it possible to let SWIG do an automatic redirect of `shared_ptr` of an object, so that if I somewhere return `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`, I can still call `print(sharedPtrToFoo)` and it will call the `__str__` or `operator<<` of the pointed to object?

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199233/str-not-called-when-printing-c-class-wrapped-for-python-with-swig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ought to work, assuming that you're not using `-builtin':

```
%extend Foo {
    std::string __str__() const {
         std::ostringstream out;
         out << *$self;
         return out.str();
    }
}
```

Note that this is substantially similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199233/str-not-called-when-printing-c-class-wrapped-for-python-with-swig#comment39388765_25276813), albeit with the recommendation to use `std::string` instead of `const char *` removing a subtle bug.

With regards to `shared_ptr` it should be that every method of `Foo` is exposed with `shared_ptr<Foo>` transparently so I'd expect that to just work.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Nice, thanks. It answers the question asked, but some might find a purely Python point useful in addition: if you want the print function to work when e.g. the mapped object is in a list, then map operator << to `__repr__` rather than `__str__`. Unless you have a good reason to distinguish `__str__` from `__repr__`, define the latter and the former will call it by default.