# swig: extending a class template to provide __str__

Tags: python, c++, swig

Say you have a template class `Foo`, and you want to wrap it with Swig transparently so that you can print the class:

```
>>> from example import *
>>> f = Foo2()
>>> print(f)
In Foo class!
```

I have followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548779/how-to-stringfy-a-swig-matrix-object-in-python) and [this one](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_class_extension). So my header file is:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int d> class Foo {

public:

  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Foo &m) {
    os << "Inside Foo class!" << std::endl;
    return os;
  }
};
```

And my interface file:

```
%{
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.hpp"
%}

%include "std_iostream.i"

// Try grabbing it unmodified
%include "foo.hpp"


/* Instantiate a few different versions of the template */
%template(Foo2) Foo<2>;
%template(Foo3) Foo<3>;


%extend Foo<2> {

  const char *__str__() {

    std::ostringstream oss(std::ostringstream::out);
    oss << *self;
    return oss.str().c_str();
  }
};
```

So this works just fine, I can print the object as before, but I would like to generalize it for any value of the template parameter, as it doesn't make sense to copy that code for every template parameter. I tried the following in the interface file but it didn't work:

```
template <int d> class Foo {

public:

  %extend {
    const char *__str__() {

      std::ostringstream oss(std::ostringstream::out);
      oss << *self;
      return oss.str().c_str();
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to `%extend` the primary template, from outside its definition, by omitting the template parameter list:

```
%extend Foo {
  const char *__str__() {
    std::ostringstream oss(std::ostringstream::out);
    oss << *self;
    return oss.str().c_str();
  }
};

%template(Foo2) Foo<2>;
%template(Foo3) Foo<3>;
```

---

Or you could use a SWIG macro to wrap and extend each specialization in one go:

```
%define WRAP_FOO(N)

  %template( Foo ## N ) Foo<N>;

  %extend Foo<N> {
    const char *__str__() {
      std::ostringstream oss(std::ostringstream::out);
      oss << *self;
      return oss.str().c_str();
    }
  };

%enddef

/* Instantiate a few different versions of the template */
WRAP_FOO(2)
WRAP_FOO(3)
```

**Note that in either case, you are causing undefined behaviour by returning the result of `.c_str()` of a `std::string` which is destroyed before the function returns.**

Comment: Thanks @Oktalist. I tried your first approach and it works just fine. I will use this for the time being, as I think it is easier to maintain that using the other solution provided in this post. By the way, I see the problem of undefined behavior you outlined. Any suggestions on how to avoid this?

Comment: If you `%include "std_string.i"` then SWIG knows how to handle `std::string`, and your `__str__()` can return `std::string` instead of `const char *`.

Comment: I changed it to `std::string __str__() {
    std::ostringstream oss(std::ostringstream::out);
    oss << *self;
    return std::string(oss.str());
  }` and it works fine, but since I'm returning a string by value it should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The `%extend` syntax you are using in your final example should be correct, this is a technique we are using in [OpenStudio](https://github.com/NREL/OpenStudio/blob/develop/openstudiocore/src/utilities/core/CommonImport.i#L104)

I believe the problem is that you are defining the template 2 times, once in your `%import` directive and once in your `.i` file. The first definition is the one that SWIG is using.

While not ideal, I believe that you'll need to drop the `%include "foo.hpp"` directive and define specifically the interface you want. Your new `.i` file becomes now something like:

```
%{
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.hpp"
%}

%include "std_iostream.i"

// Don't let SWIG directly parse foo.hpp
// %include "foo.hpp"



template <int d> class Foo {

public:
  // include here prototypes for all functions
  // you want exposed. You don't need the implementation like in 
  // a normal C++ template declaration

  // include here any extensions you want to add
  %extend {
    const char *__str__() {

      std::ostringstream oss(std::ostringstream::out);
      oss << *self;
      return oss.str().c_str();
    }
  }
};

/* Instantiate a few different versions of the template */
%template(Foo2) Foo<2>;
%template(Foo3) Foo<3>;
```

---

Alternatively, you could place the SWIG code in your hpp file directly and save having to maintain two APIs:

New .i file:

```
%{
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.hpp"
%}

%include "std_iostream.i"

// let swig directly parse foo.hpp
%include "foo.hpp"


/* Instantiate a few different versions of the template */
%template(Foo2) Foo<2>;
%template(Foo3) Foo<3>;
```

New .hpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int d> class Foo {

public:
#ifdef SWIG
  %extend {
    const char *__str__() {

      std::ostringstream oss(std::ostringstream::out);
      oss << *self;
      return oss.str().c_str();
    }
  }
#endif

  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Foo &m) {
    os << "Inside Foo class!" << std::endl;
    return os;
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for answering. But this would mean that I would have to maintain two files from a file whose interface is not even close to being finished. Isn't this going to be a maintenance nightmare?

Comment: Well, you do have an alternative in that you could add a `#ifdef SWIG` block inside your .hpp. I don't personally like muddying up the C++ API with code like that, but you have to decide who your target user is - the C++ user or the SWIG user. Making an API that works VERY WELL for both, is difficult, and tradeoffs have to happen at some point. I'll update my answer with the other possibility.

Comment: I ended up implementing what was suggested by Oktalist, as it seems I don't need to maintain two files. Thanks @lefticus for your suggestions!

Comment: @aaragon I agree, his solution was better. Be sure to "accept" it so he gets credit for it.